# scatter plot points don't maintain value when zooming in d3.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, d3.js

This is my first time using d3.js, so please bear with me. I am implementing this inside of a vue.js file as pure javascript.
I am trying to make a scatter plot with zooming capabilities. So far I have everything nearly working, but when I zoom I notice that the x-axis isn't scaling properly, but the y-axis is working properly. For instance, when looking at the original plot, a point may be at around 625 on the x-axis, but after zooming in the same point will be less than 600. This is not happening with the y-axis - those points scale properly. I am assuming that something is wrong with the scaling of the x-axis in my zoom function, but I just can't figure it out. Please take a look, and let me know if you can see where I went wrong.

Edit: I should mention that this is using d3.js version 7.4.4

```
<template>
    <div id="reg_plot"></div>
</template>


<script>
import * as d3 from 'd3';
export default {
    name: 'regCamGraph',
    components: {
        d3
    },
    methods: {
        createSvg() {
            // dimensions
            var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
                svg_dx = 1400, 
                svg_dy =1000,
                chart_dx = svg_dx - margin.right - margin.left,
                chart_dy = svg_dy - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            // data
            var y = d3.randomNormal(400, 100);
            var x_jitter = d3.randomUniform(-100, 1400);

            var d = d3.range(1000)
                        .map(function() { 
                            return [x_jitter(), y()]; 
                        });

            // fill
            var colorScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                                .domain(d3.extent(d, function(d) { return d[1]; }))
                                .range([0, 1]);


            // y position
            var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                            .domain(d3.extent(d, function(d) { return d[1]; }))
                            .range([chart_dy, margin.top]);
            
            // x position
            var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                            .domain(d3.extent(d, function(d) { return d[0]; }))
                            .range([margin.right, chart_dx]);
            console.log("chart_dy: " + chart_dy);
            console.log("margin.top: " + margin.top);
            console.log("chart_dx: " + chart_dx);
            console.log("margin.right: " + margin.right);
            // y-axis
            var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);

            // x-axis
            var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);

            // zoom
            var svg = d3.select("#reg_plot")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", svg_dx)
                        .attr("height", svg_dy);
            svg.call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", zoom));      // ref [1]

            // plot data
            var circles = svg.append("g")
                            .attr("id", "circles")
                            .attr("transform", "translate(200, 0)")
                            .selectAll("circle")
                            .data(d)
                            .enter()
                            .append("circle")
                            .attr("r", 4)
                            .attr("cx", function(d) { return xScale(d[0]); })
                            .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d[1]); })
                            .style("fill", function(d) { 
                                var norm_color = colorScale(d[1]);
                                return d3.interpolateInferno(norm_color) 
                            });

            // add y-axis
            var y_axis = svg.append("g")
                            .attr("id", "y_axis")
                            .attr("transform", "translate(75,0)")
                            .call(yAxis).style("font-size", "20px")
                        
            // add x-axis
            var x_axis = svg.append("g")
                            .attr("id", "x_axis")
                            .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left}, ${svg_dy - margin.bottom})`)
                            .call(xAxis).style("font-size", "20px")

            function zoom(e) {

                // re-scale y axis during zoom
                y_axis.transition()
                        .duration(50)
                        .call(yAxis.scale(e.transform.rescaleY(yScale)));

                // re-scale x axis during zoom
                x_axis.transition()
                        .duration(50)
                        .call(xAxis.scale(e.transform.rescaleX(xScale)));

                // re-draw circles using new y-axis scale
                var new_xScale = e.transform.rescaleX(xScale);
                var new_yScale = e.transform.rescaleY(yScale);

                console.log(d);

                x_axis.call(xAxis.scale(new_xScale));
                y_axis.call(yAxis.scale(new_yScale));
                circles.data(d)
                    .attr('cx', function(d) {return new_xScale(d[0])})
                    .attr('cy', function(d) {return new_yScale(d[1])});
            }

        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.createSvg();
    }
    
}
</script>
```

Interestingly enough, after I set the clip region to prevent showing points outside of the axes the problem seemed to resolve itself. This is how I created the clip path:

```
// clip path
            var clip = svg.append("defs").append("svg:clipPath")
            .attr("id", "clip")
            .append("svg:rect")
            .attr("id", "clip-rect")
            .attr("x", "0")
            .attr("y", "0")
            .attr('width', chart_dx)
            .attr('height', chart_dy);
```

And I then added that attribute to the svg when plotting the data like this:

```
svg.append("g").attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
```

Updated clip path with plot data section:

```
// clip path
            var clip = svg.append("defs").append("svg:clipPath")
            .attr("id", "clip")
            .append("svg:rect")
            .attr("id", "clip-rect")
            .attr("x", "0")
            .attr("y", "0")
            .attr('width', chart_dx)
            .attr('height', chart_dy);

            // plot data
            var circles = svg.append("g")
                            .attr("id", "circles")
                            .attr("transform", "translate(75, 0)")
                            .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)") //added here
                            .selectAll("circle")
                            .data(d)
                            .enter()
                            .append("circle")
                            .attr("r", 4)
                            .attr("cx", function(d) { return xScale(d[0]); })
                            .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d[1]); })
                            .style("fill", function(d) { 
                                var norm_color = colorScale(d[1]);
                                return d3.interpolateInferno(norm_color) 
                            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up resolving this issue. I have updated the original post to show what worked for me.

Basically, after adding the clip region things started to work properly.

```
// clip path (this is the new clip region that I added. It prevents dots from being drawn outside of the axes.
            var clip = svg.append("defs").append("svg:clipPath")
            .attr("id", "clip")
            .append("svg:rect")
            .attr("id", "clip-rect")
            .attr("x", "0")
            .attr("y", "0")
            .attr('width', chart_dx)
            .attr('height', chart_dy);

            // plot data
            var circles = svg.append("g")
                            .attr("id", "circles")
                            .attr("transform", "translate(75, 0)")
                            .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)") //added clip region to svg here
                            .selectAll("circle")
                            .data(d)
                            .enter()
                            .append("circle")
                            .attr("r", 4)
                            .attr("cx", function(d) { return xScale(d[0]); })
                            .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d[1]); })
                            .style("fill", function(d) { 
                                var norm_color = colorScale(d[1]);
                                return d3.interpolateInferno(norm_color) 
                            });
```